# Routing website through another IP

Tags: wordpress, server

I am wondering if its possible to route my website through different IP according to different region of a country.
For example
I have a London business directory - it is hosted on a London server
I have a Scotland business directory - it is hosted on a London server

I am curious to know if it is possible to route it through an IP for a different region. London site seems to be doing very well in terms of SEO the only difference is the site name, content and URL is matching London, the location of the server.

Is it possible to get floating IP or something for different region, we would like to test if this improves ranking on SEO.

Many thanks its UBuntu apache wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a GEO-based loadbalancer.. The easiest way to achieve this is probably the use of a CDN

Comment: Thankyou, I am using digital ocean as server host but they only have servers in London and other countries. I shall look into CDN as we have MaxCDN content delivery network on one of our other websites.

Comment: Does anyone know an affordable (or even free load balancer or delivery network ) for Wordpress? Thanks in advance